# Diagram editor using WPF/Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I need to develop something similar to Visio editor using either WPF or Windows Forms.

[image: Layout example]

Basic functionality is a palette with arrows and rectangles that can be dragged and dropped onto container, connected to each other, Copy-cut-paste, Undo/Redo etc. How can I achieve this in case with WPF and in case with Windows Forms ?

So far,my best shots are these following links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-VZFC2TLCU

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part

(I don't have much experience with WPF)     Maybe somebody can provide better tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [NOV Diagram for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-diagram-control-overview). It's a fully managed, cross-platform diagramming framework that lets you create diagramming solutions for WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and Xamarin.Mac. NOV Diagram for .NET provides many of the features available in Visio, including a formula engine and support for smart shapes. Check out [NOV Diagram's website](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-diagram-control-overview) for a list of its features, screenshots and a free trial version that comes with many examples.

The following screenshot demonstrates the widgets provided by [NOV Diagram for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-diagram-control-overview):

[image: NOV Diagram for .NET UI]

Disclosure: I work for Nevron.